# How get size of blob in PHP or SQL

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have lots of blob data in my database, and I need to retrieve the weight (400kb, 14,2kb etc.) for each.

How can I do that?

Comment: you wanna select the data from db or wanna know size of that blob text?

Comment: What is the structure of the table?

Comment: What DBMS do you use and what type is your blob data column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQL:

```
SELECT some_key, LENGTH(blob_column) AS size_in_bytes FROM the_table
```

In PHP:

```
$sizes = array();
foreach (how_you_query_the_db('SELECT some_key, blob_column FROM the_table ') as $row)
  $sizes[$row['some_key']] = strlen($row['blob_column']);
```

Comment: In phpmyadmin, i see for example a blob with 18,2Ko. With your script, i retrieve 18609... do you know why ?

Comment: 18609 / 1024 = 18.17285... which is, rounded to 1 decimal, 18.2. You should be able to get the same result with `CONCAT(ROUND(LENGTH(blob_column)/1024, 1), 'k')`.