# What is the $path of my item in my SQL database so I can download?

Tags: php, mysql

I have found posts that explain how to download a a file (in my case an MP3) from an SQL database in PHP. It is apparent that a $path of the file is necessary in order to enable the download. I have the MP3 uploaded to my database but don't have the path uploaded because I don't know what it would be. I am accustomed to accessing my objects through an associative array such as: $row['wholeMP3']; The item is stored as a longblob in the database. I don't understand what my $path would be for this item. If someone could please explain to me further it would be appreciated.

```
<?php
query2 = "SELECT* FROM MP3s_for_Sale WHERE id = :itemNum";
$LastProduct = $db->prepare($query2);
$LastProduct->bindvalue(':itemNum', $itemNum);
$LastProduct->execute();
//Need to figure out how to download
$rows = $LastProduct->fetchAll();
$LastProduct->closeCursor();
foreach ($rows as $row){
// I have created a column for the filename and extension called path
$filename = $row['path'];
$filesize = $row['filesize'];

//$size = filesize($yourfile);
//echo "size ".$size;
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");
header("Content-Length: $filesize");
//what is $yourfile?
//readfile($yourfile);
//I put this here and it does transfer a file just not operable
echo $row['wholeMP3']; 
} 
?>
```

Here is an update using an example I found on stackoverflow. I now have
columns for size, path/name, type and content in my table. I filled in the required fields and it still doesn't work. It begins to download and then just stops. This is is my new code:

```
$query2 = "SELECT* FROM MP3s_for_Sale WHERE id = :itemNum";
$LastProduct = $db->prepare($query2);
$LastProduct->bindvalue(':itemNum', $itemNum);
$LastProduct->execute();
//Need to figure out how to download
$rows = $LastProduct->fetchAll();
$LastProduct->closeCursor();
foreach ($rows as $row){
$filename = $row['path'];
$filesize = $row['filesize'];
$content =  $row['wholeMP3'];
$type = $row['type']; 

header("Content-length: $filesize");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $content;
}
exit;
```

Comment: There’s no path dude. You need to send the binary blob directly.

Comment: Could you please explain further. The code I have seen requires $yourfile to be a path. I don't know any other approach about how to download.

Comment: I guess you stored a "path" in your db and uploaded the file to your server. This means that with the select all you need to do is get that file path from the db and the file should download

Comment: @SuperDJ the question clearly states "The item is stored as a longblob in the database". If `$row['wholeMP3']` was a filename this code would work nicely.

Comment: I didn't store a path in my database yet because I don't know what it is. Thanks for your help but I don't understand.

Comment: munson I think your problem stems from passing the binary blob to `filesize()` when it's not a file. See if this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122700/how-get-size-of-blob-in-php-or-sql gives you any help trying to get the size of the data. Then at the end you can just `echo $row['wholeMP3']` to output it to the client

Comment: It would be easier that way tough. It would also save a lot of space in your db. Normally you would set a path in the http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php function.

Comment: @SuperDJ yeah and probably quicker to execute too, but we're past that point. The binary data is already in the DB, so unless OP re-designs the application significantly then it's not going to be a solution

Comment: When I pass the file name in place of $row['wholeMP3']; I get filesize() stat failed. I still don't understand. Please advise.

Comment: I am still stuck on this one. I created a new path column in my sql table. There the file name and extension are stored. I guess this is the path? Thats what I refer to in the code. Doesn't give size but an error.

Comment: You haven't got a file. You clearly stated that the contents you wish to send for download are stored in the database field. That's why I said to find another way of finding the size of the _data_ (and forget about files on disk. The data you've got is what is needed to make an mp3, sure, and it'll turn into a file when it hits the user's browser, but until then it's just an array of bytes).

Comment: But I do need the size. I guess I can find that out on upload and store it in the table right?

Comment: I don't understand what $yourfile is suppose to be. I have no idea.

Comment: I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291361/how-to-download-blob-based-file-from-mysql-database-in-php

Comment: I am now experiencing difficulty with closing out of paypal. Please tell me if yall know anything.

Comment: @munson $yourfile in the context of the filesize function is supposed to be a path/filename of a file on disk - http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php. But since you don't have a file on disk, that's why you can't use that function. Anyway looks like you figured it out based on that other example. Checking and storing the filesize at the time of upload is a sensible solution. If you have a separate problem regarding paypal then you'll need a new question, nothing in what you've written here tells us anything about what your issue with that is.